# Filtering ng-repeat when object property is empty with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects with multiple properties. All of these objects have a `object.comment` property, but in some is filled with a string (`'comment' : 'comment text'`), and the others are empty (`'comment' : ''`).

I list the results with an ng-repeat like so:

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist | filter:dateFilter | filter: search )" 
>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to add a checkbox filter to show only the results which `object.comment` property is filled when the checkbox is checked, and all results when is unchecked.

Here's how my filter looks so far:

```
<form role="form">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <input type='daterange' 
              placeholder="Date range" 
              class="form-control"
              format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
              ng-model="dates"
              ranges="ranges" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time" ng-model="search.time">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Car" ng-model="search.car">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Driver" ng-model="search.driver">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="From" ng-model="search.from">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Destination" ng-model="search.destination">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Pax" ng-model="search.pax">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" 
                         ng-model="search.cancelled" 
                         ng-change="search.cancelled = search.cancelled ? true : undefined"
                  > Cancelled 
                </label>
              </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" 
                         ng-model="search.comment" 
                         ng-change="search.comment = search.comment ? true : undefined"
                  > Commented records
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

</form>
```

As you can see, I already have a filter that works on whether the `object.cancelled` is true or false, but I didn't manage to do the same for when the `object.comment` is empty or has a string.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom filter please see demo below

```
app.filter('emptyString', [
  function() {
    return function(input, param) {
      if (!param) return input

      var ret = [];
      if (!angular.isDefined(param)) param = true;


      if (param) {
        angular.forEach(input, function(v) {
          if (angular.isDefined(v.comment) && v.comment) {
            v.comment = v.comment.replace(/^\s*/g, '');
            ret.push(v);
          }

        });
      }



      return ret;
    };
  }
])
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.recordlist = [{
      time: "10/11/2014",
      comment: "super"
    }, {
      time: "10/11/20004",
      comment: ""
    }, {
      time: "10/11/2005",
      comment: ""
    }, {
      time: "11/1/2014",
      comment: "that was ok"
    }


  ];


});

app.filter('emptyString', [
  function() {
    return function(input, param) {
      if (!param) return input

      var ret = [];
      if (!angular.isDefined(param)) param = true;


      if (param) {
        angular.forEach(input, function(v) {
          if (angular.isDefined(v.comment) && v.comment) {
            v.comment = v.comment.replace(/^\s*/g, '');
            ret.push(v);
          }

        });
      }



      return ret;
    };
  }
])
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type='daterange' placeholder="Date range" class="form-control" format="DD/MM/YYYY" ng-model="dates" ranges="ranges" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time" ng-model="search.time">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Car" ng-model="search.car">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Driver" ng-model="search.driver">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="From" ng-model="search.from">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Destination" ng-model="search.destination">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Pax" ng-model="search.pax">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.cancelled" ng-change="search.cancelled = search.cancelled ? true : undefined">Cancelled
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.comment">Commented records
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row " ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist |  emptyString : search.comment   )">
        <div class="col-xs-12" <span class="label">{{record.time}} <span> <strong>{{record.comment}}</strong></p> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the `ng-hide` directive:

```
<div class="row"
    ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords"
    ng-hide="search.comment && (!record.comment || record.comment === '')">
</div>
```

What it says is: Hide this element if `search.comment` is checked and the `record.comment` is undefined or empty.

Check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8rA0rVxqgWS0NWukJdf?p=preview

Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: If I do ng-hide="record.comment === ''", it will work and show only the ones with comment, but I can't get it working with the search.comment toggle using the checkbox!

Comment: @EricMitjans Did you use the whole condition? I mean, `ng-hide="search.comment && (record.comment || record.comment === '')"`

Comment: Yes! It filters all results out! : /

Comment: @EricMitjans Ok, I found an error, check the updated answer and plunker.

Comment: Now it works! I realized I cannot use it, but is for another reason. If I use a filter, it takes much more resources and its slower, but I can create a new array with the filtered results (e.g:  `ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist | filter: search )"`. I need to do this as I am calculating the .length of the resulting array (filteredRecords) and even downloading the filtered results, so ng-hide doesn't work for me (it filters the results visually, but not in the new array), but is a very nice solution anyways! I'll use it in other ng-repeats!